# How to set up my form to send an object

Tags: angular, forms, rest, typescript, drupal

Okay, this is what Drupal wants to create a node.

**Nodes**
**Create**

**POST:** http://example.com/entity/node
**Content-type:** application/json

> ```
> {
>   "type":[{"target_id":"article"}],
>   "title":[{"value":"Hello World"}],
>   "body":[{"value":"How are you?"}]
> }
> ```

I am following the Tour of heroes, so this is my actual reference to send post methods:

**Form in the template**

```
  <label>Task name:
    <input #taskName type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required>
  </label>
  <button (click)="add(taskName.value); taskName.value=''" class="btn btn-success">
    add
  </button>
</div>
```

**This is how I get the form** and send it to the Service

```
add(name: string): void {
  name = name.trim();
  if (!name) { return; }
  this.taskService.addTask({ name } as Task)
    .subscribe(Task => {
      this.tasks.push(Task);
    });
```

**And this trow me this:**

> {"name":"asd"}

So, in the console i got this:

> 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

I can ask for more fields in the form and send them with the post method, so **my question is: how do I have to set up the form to send all the fields in the way that Drupal wants.**

This is my best approach:

**The new form**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="TaskData()" #taskForm="ngForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required #taskName>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="alterEgo">Body</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="body" #taskBody>
  </div>    
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**The new TaskData function:**

```
TaskData(name: string, body: string): void {
  this.taskService.addTask({ name, body } as Task)
    .subscribe(Task => {
      this.tasks.push(Task);
    });
}
```

But obviously something is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could build your object with something like this in your .ts file

```
TaskData(name: string, body: string){
   let data: any = {
      type: [],
      title: [],
      body: []     
   };
   data.type.push({target_id: id});
   data.title.push({value: name});
   data.body.push({value: body});

   this.taskService.addTask(data).subscribe(
      doSomeThing();
   );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i did what you did,     **onSubmit** (name: string, body: string) { 

   **let task** : any = {
       type: [],
       title: [],
       body: []     
    };
    **task.type.push** ({target_id: "task"});
    **task.title.push** ({value: name});
    **task.body.push** ({value: body});
    **console.log** (JSON.stringify(task));
    }  **this is the result of the console log:** {"type":[{"target_id":"task"}],"title":[{}],"body":[{}]}. **I got an empty title and body**

Comment: In the form i had to add this: <form (ngSubmit)=" **onSubmit**
 (taskName.value, taskBody.value)" #heroForm="ngForm">